# How to make a one to many relation ship Using EF Core (Repository Pattern)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first-mapping

i am trying to make relation "Student has many StudentRecords" using repository pattern. when i run migration facing below error.Kindly let me know what should i do in on model Creating method.

"The property 'Student.StudentRecord' is of type 'StudentRecord' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

```
  public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EnrollmentNo { get; set; }

    public StudentRecord StudentRecord { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my mapping class and Context's on modelCreating mathod.

```
class StudentMap
{
    public StudentMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.FirstName).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.LastName).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Email).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.EnrollmentNo).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.StudentRecord).IsRequired();
    }

}
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new StudentMap(modelBuilder.Entity<Student>());
        new StudentRecordMapp(modelBuilder.Entity<StudentRecord>());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `StudentRecord`? Another entity class? Please include that class in the question.

Comment: yes, student Record is another entity class

Answer (score 1):

In `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentRecord>()
.HasOne(x => x.Student)
.WithMany(x => x.StudentRecords)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentID)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Your entities:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentRecord> StudentRecords { get; set; }
}

public class StudentRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```